# Where (on OSX) is the Flash CS4 crash log?

Tags: flash, logging, crash, cs4

I have one particular FLA that is crashing every time I try to compile (after switching to Snow Leopard). Flash just stalls and I am forced to use "Force Quit"... I have no idea what could be causing this and I cannot find any crash report. Where on the system does Flash put crash logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter`.

Comment: Thanks! Will start another thread to see if anyone can actually decipher this crash log.